# Javascript onload

Tags: javascript, onload

I am using xmlhttp to display thumbnails in a div in increments of 15, something like Google Images. When the request starts it turns on the display property of an "loading.gif" which is then turned off when a counter reaches 15. This counter is incremented by the onload event of the each thumbnail. My problem is that onload does not fire for broken thumbnails, so my counter sometimes never reaches 15; how to solve this? I rather not to use Jquery.

Comment: Add an `error` event handler and increase the counter there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onError event as well to remove it or trigger the counter too.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp